# sprite kit nodes do not removeFromParent

Tags: nsarray, sprite-kit

hi there I am making a game with Sprite Kit and I have a method which has a NSArray, a for loop and some SKACTIONS. Now, this array has 7 items. the for loop randomly picks up one of the array's content and shows on the screen and using SKActions, that item scales down and another scales up. however, at the bottom of the similuator, it shows that numbers of nodes keep piling up. for example, if one sprite appears, instead of 1 node, 4 nodes shows as the number of nodes at the bottom of Simulator's screen. What do you think might be wrong here?

here is my code.

```
-(void) ItemMakerMe {
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item1", @"item2", @"item3", @"item4", @"item5",  @"item6", @"MyNull", nil];
    NSUInteger arraypicker = arc4random() % [myArray count];
    for (int i=0; i < arraypicker; ++i) {
        NSString *d1 = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
        sprites = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:d1];
        sprites.name = @"items";
        sprites.position = CGPointMake(ScalarRandomRange(0, self.size.width/2), ScalarRandomRange(0, self.size.height/2));
        sprites.xScale = 0;
        sprites.yScale = 0;
        [self addChild:sprites];
    }
}

-(void) OneItemONLY {
    SKAction *appear = [SKAction scaleTo:0.19 duration:0.5];
    SKAction *waiter = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5];
    SKAction *scaleDown = [SKAction scaleTo:0.0 duration:0.5];
    SKAction *remover = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    [sprites runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[appear, waiter, scaleDown, remover]]];
}
```

Also in the init method I run it like this:

```
  [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction performSelector:@selector(ItemMakerMe) onTarget:self],
                                                                     [SKAction waitForDuration:2.0]]]]];

  [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction performSelector:@selector(OneItemONLY) onTarget:self],
                                                                     [SKAction waitForDuration:2.0]]]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, I believe that the for loop runs the action of the last node of `i` value but still adds the other sprites before the loop ends.

I.E: Lets say the `arraypicker` has a value of 4, then the for-loop will then select the `NSString` from the array, initialize the `sprites` object with the image, name, position, etc and then **it is added to self's children, this repeats 4 times** but only the last added instance of `sprites` will have the image you want and will run the actions.

What I mean is that if you only want to select a random value from the array, and set its properties maybe you could remove the for-loop.

Summary: `[self addChild:sprites]` is adding the same object `i` times and is causing an increment of nodes.

Comment: Thanks actually that this solve the repetitive problem but here is another one. this loop was supposed to loop through the array and based on the random count from the array, it should have return one of the array's items every one but different one every time but now it only picks 1 of the item every time. so any suggestions bud?

Comment: Do you mean select a random item from the array but then not repeat itself? You could remove that item from the array after the image is added.
Call: [myArray removeObject:d1]; after [self addChild:sprites];

Comment: Actually not removing it because what it is, is that it doesn't show like 5 of the same item on the screen. it shows only one of the same kind but in the node number at the right down side of the simulator, it shows like from 15 nodes to 20 nodes with addition of a single sprite on screen.